# Updating a Single Value in hashicorp Vault

Tags: json, curl, hashicorp-vault

I am running a hashicorp vault server that works great in providing secrets and other sensitive information to the application servers.

Secrets are stored as json object in the secrets and application retrieve and parse them as json objects

The issue i am facing is that i am unable to update a single value in the secrets file. Can anyone tell me how to update a single value in the json format secrets file?

Below is a sample secrets file that we have

```
{
  "data": {
    "cloud.aws.credentials.accessKey": "AWS_KEY",
    "cloud.aws.credentials.secretKey": "akjdfhadsFADSFadsfadksbfadsfADSF123123",
    "cloud.aws.region.static": "AWS_REGION",
    "app.base.url": "http://app.env.abc:8080",
    "app.password": "ThisIsASamplePassword",
    "app.base.url": "http://localhost:7070/applicationname",
    "app.user.name": "this.is.a.sample"
  }
}
```

we are using quite a few AWS Access keys and our security policy is to rotate a key every 60 days.

Prior to vault we were rotating using a bash script and aws cli commands but I am unable to find a way to do that in vault

To retrieve the value via `vault kv get` command I get

```
====== Metadata ======
Key              Value
---              -----
created_time     2019-05-08T08:29:59.3579731Z
deletion_time    n/a
destroyed        false
version          2

==== Data ====
Key     Value
---     -----
data    map[cloud.aws.credentials.accessKey:AWS_KEY cloud.aws.credentials.secretKey:akjdfhadsFADSFadsfadksbfadsfADSF123123 cloud.aws.region.static:AWS_REGION app.base.url:http://localhost:7070/applicationname app.password:ThisIsASamplePassword app.user.name:this.is.a.sample]
```

I have tried `patch` command but that only overwrites the whole value or create a new key/value.

````
Key              Value
---              -----
created_time     2019-05-08T08:33:57.5164447Z
deletion_time    n/a
destroyed        false
version          3
[ansible@ntt00app32 tmp]$ vault kv get secret/cms-service,devint
====== Metadata ======
Key              Value
---              -----
created_time     2019-05-08T08:33:57.5164447Z
deletion_time    n/a
destroyed        false
version          3

================= Data =================
Key                                Value
---                                -----
cloud.aws.credentials.accessKey    TEST_KEY
data                               map[cloud.aws.region.static:AWS_REGION app.base.url:http://localhost:7070/applicationname app.password:ThisIsASamplePassword app.user.name:this.is.a.sample cloud.aws.credentials.accessKey:AWS_KEY cloud.aws.credentials.secretKey:akjdfhadsFADSFadsfadksbfadsfADSF123123]```

any help in doing this will be much appreciated.
````

Comment: patch is the command for you. can you share what exactly is not working? and have a look at https://learn.hashicorp.com/vault/secrets-management/sm-versioned-kv (search patch)

Comment: I am not sure about the patch command would be helpful. Below is what i get 

```====== Metadata ======
Key              Value
---              -----
created_time     2019-05-08T08:29:59.3579731Z
deletion_time    n/a
destroyed        false
version          2

==== Data ====
Key     Value
---     -----
data    map[cloud.aws.credentials.accessKey:AWS_KEY cloud.aws.credentials.secretKey:akjdfhadsFADSFadsfadksbfadsfADSF123123 cloud.aws.region.static:AWS_REGION app.base.url:http://localhost:7070/applicationname app.password:ThisIsASamplePassword app.user.name:this.is.a.sample]```

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question. Updating a single value in hashicorp vault where the secrets are stored as json object can be done easily using cURL, JQ and some bash scripting.

Crude script is pasted below that can be modified to the requirements

```
#!/bin/bash

TOKEN="<TOKEN>"
VALUE_ONE="This"
VAULE_TWO="That"

# Retrieving secret
object=$(curl -s --header X-Vault-Token:$TOKEN http://127.0.0.1:8200/v1/secret/data/appname)

# Retrieving block that we are interested in (Optional)
new_object=$(echo $object | /usr/bin/jq -r '.data')

# Replacing First Value
replace_VALUE_ONE=$(echo $new_object | jq '.data."vaule.one" = '\"$VALUE_ONE\"'')

# Replacing Second Value
final=$(echo $replace_VALUE_ONE | jq '.data."vaule.two" = '\"$VAULE_TWO\"'')

# Updating the Vault
curl --header X-Vault-Token:$TOKEN  --request POST --data "$final"  http://127.0.0.1:8200/v1/secret/data/appname

# Retrieving the secret again 
curl -s --header X-Vault-Token:$TOKEN  http://127.0.0.1:8200/v1/secret/data/appname
```

Answer (score 2):

[`vault kv patch`](https://developer.hashicorp.com/vault/docs/commands/kv/patch) does this job, no need to use `curl` to get and replace the value.

> Unlike the `kv put` command, the `patch` command combines the change with existing data instead of replacing them.

So it can be used either to replace value of an existing field or to add a new field with a new value.

```bash
# update
vault kv patch -mount=secret <secret_path> existing_value="update_value"
# add
vault kv patch -mount=secret <secret_path> new_value="new_value"
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).